# Sharepoint can not find back to the document library when saving file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

When I click "New document" button on my document library and then click on save to save back the file to the library it has chosen my document folder on my computer instead of the document library on the SharePoint Site. What is the problem and how can I fix it? thanks for your advice. The Document library uses my content type which is inherited from Document Content Type.